# Construction of a random variable

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm reading *Dirichlet Forms and Symmetric Markov Processes* by M. Fukushima, Y. Oshima, and M. Takeda.  In Appendix A.2, where they discuss the construction of a random variable, there is the statement:

> "..., we need  a non-negative random variable $Z(\omega)$ on
>   $(\Omega,\mathcal{M},P_{x})$ which is of exponential distribution with
>   mean $1$; independent of $(X_{t})_{t \ge 0}$ under $P_{x}$ for every
>   $x \in S$ satisfying $Z(\theta_{s}(\omega))=(Z(\omega)-s)\vee 0$."

In the statement, $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, (X_{t})_{t \ge 0}, (P_{x})_{x \in S})$ is a Hunt process with state space $S$ and $(\theta_{t})_{t \ge 0}$ is a shift operator of this Hunt process.

This book says,

> "This requirement is fulfilled by replacing $\Omega$ by its direct
>   with $[0,\infty)$ if necessary. To see this, let $Z(\xi)$ be a
>   non-negative random variable on $([0,\infty), \mathcal{B}([0,\infty)),
>  \lambda)$ of exponent distribution with mean $1$; $\lambda(\left\{ \xi
>  \ge 0; Z(\xi) >a \right\})=e^{-a}$, $\forall a \ge 0$. We can consider
>   the functions $X_{t},\theta_{t}$ and $Z$ as function on $\Omega
>  \otimes [0,\infty)$ by putting $X_{t}(\omega,\xi)=X_{t}(\omega),
>  \theta_{t}(\omega ,\xi)=(\theta_{t}(\omega),(\xi-t)^{+})$ and
>   $Z(\omega,\xi)=Z(\xi)$, $\forall (\omega, \xi) \in \Omega \otimes
>  [0,\infty)$. It is clear, under this identification, that $(\Omega
>  \otimes [0,\infty), \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{B}([0,\infty)),
>  X_{t}, P_{x}\otimes \lambda)$ is a Hunt process with admissible
>   filtration $\mathcal{M}_{t}\otimes \mathcal{B}([0,\infty))$ and that
>   the random variable $Z$ has the desired properties."

**Question**

I don't understand $Z$ satisfies $Z(\theta_{s}(\omega ,\xi))=(Z(\omega,\xi)-s)\vee 0$. By definition,
\begin{align}
Z(\theta_{s}(\omega,\xi))&=Z(\theta_{s}(\omega), (\xi-s)^{+}) \\
&=Z((\xi-s)^{+}) \\
&=Z(\omega, (\xi-s)^{+} ).
\end{align}

How do I get the equation $Z(\theta_{s}(\omega ,\xi))=(Z(\omega,\xi)-s)\vee 0$ ?
Doing somethig wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Presumably they just meant to write $Z(w,\xi) = \xi$ (and similarly replace $Z(\xi)$ by $\xi$ in the definition of $\lambda$)...